# Cannot receive files using Bluetooth on Karbonn Android One

Tags: bluetooth, file-transfer, karbonn

I have Karbonn Android One. It is unable to receive files via Bluetooth from any Android device, but there is no problem with sending files to every device.

I could not understand what's the problem. How can I receive files using Bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your phone... This usually works. Remember to take a backup.

Comment: Try resetting the phone? because the phone wont receive files via bluetooth? seems a bit extreme, don't you think? Wipe the entire phone and have to set everything back up.